# Solicitar que a pergunta seja marcada como respondida

Tags: debate

Se um usuário faz uma pergunta, outro responde com a informação necessária, o *perguntador* chega a comentar abaixo da resposta que aquela informação foi útil, mas no fim não marca a resposta aceita.

Qual a melhor maneira, indicada pelo site, pra solicitar ao perguntador que marque a pergunta como *respondida*?